# Prevent Select from changing selected option if condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box. Currently, this select box make an ajax call on `change`.

Now, I want to make call only when a condition is met.

So, here is my code:

```
$('#buildingSelect').on('change', function(){
    var result = checkDirtyStatus();
    //this checkDirtyStatus alert message if there is some changes on the form.
    //if cancel return false, if confirm return true.
    if(result === false) {
        return;
    }
    //make ajax call
});
```

This prevents from making ajax call, however, this change the selected option of the select i.e, if `option1` is selected at the begining and if I try to select next option then it will change the selected option to `option2` then only check the status.

On searching on the internet, I got the option of `focusin`.

```
$('#buildingSelect').on('focusin', function(){
    // console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    var result = checkDirtyStatus();
    if(result === false) {
        return;
    }
}).on('change', function(){
    g_building_id = $(this).val();
    getAmenitiesDetails(g_building_id);
});
```

However, using this `focusin` options makes the alert box to appear everytime no matter either I click `cancel` or `ok`. This might be because, it call `focusin` again whenevr I click `Ok` or `Cancel`.

[image: screenshot of alert]

What would be the best option to check this status, and if result is false, I don't want to change the selected option as well.

### Update

Answer from marked as duplicate not preventing from changing the selected option. Its making ajax call on click i.e. before checking condition.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/prying/pen/XWrxKMb?editors=1111)

```
function checkDirtyStatus(){
        dirtyStatus = true;
        if(dirtyStatus === true){
            if (confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.")) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this does not work. It is still changing the selected value

Comment: This does work absolutely fine, as you can see in the example in the duplicate itself. If it does not work *for you* then there's an issue somewhere in your code. Please update your question to include it so we can help you debug.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You can check the codepen link provide in the question its just making unnecessary ajax call on click, this means how it is preventing from ajax call when my intention was to check condition before ajax call.

Comment: That's because the click happens *every* time. You need to make the AJAX call in the `if (result === false)` block, as the 'dirty' check passed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could you please provide the link of the codepen link. I have update the code here https://codepen.io/prying/pen/XWrxKMb?editors=1111. Here, it prevent for the first time. If you select ok, it will make ajax call, that's totally fine. However, after that it is sending ajax call on every click there after.
To reproduce, select  `option 2` click on `Ok`. After that jus `on click` its sending ajax call.

Comment: You first example, where you only do something if the value changes, is mostly fine. You check specifically for if the result from  `checkDirtyStatus` return a Boolean and that is false. I think that's where your problem is. Try change it to `if(!result) return`. Notice the exclamation mark? It is the logical NOT-operator. Now it will return even if the result is undefined.

Comment: @some could you please show with the code I don't think it should make much more difference, because I don't think the result could be undefined. As you can check the added `checkDirtyStatus()` function

Answer (score 2):

Finally, by mixing the link from Rory and idea of organizing code from some. I have find a solution for my problem. So, if anyone got stuck on the similar problem here is my solution.

```
$(function(){
    var lastSel;
    $('#buildingSelect').on('focusin', function(){
        lastSel = $("#buildingSelect option:selected");
    }).on('change', function(){
        if(!checkDirtyStatus()) {
            lastSel.prop("selected", true);
            return;
        }else{
            //made ajax call
           //$.ajax({})
        }
    });
});
function checkDirtyStatus(){
        let dirtyStatus = getDirtyStatus();
        if(dirtyStatus){
            return confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at your function:

```
function checkDirtyStatus(){
  dirtyStatus = true; // I assume this is only for testing
  if(dirtyStatus === true){ // This can be simplified.
    if (confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.")) {
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

[confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) returns a Boolean that is either true or false, so you can simplify your function like this:

```
function checkDirtyStatus(){
  dirtyStatus = true;
  if(dirtyStatus){
    return confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.");
  }
  // Notice that you do not return anything here. That means that
  // the function will return undefined.
}
```

Your other function can be simplified like this:

```
$('#buildingSelect').on('change', function(){
  if(!checkDirtyStatus()){
    // Here you probably want to set the value of the select-element to the
    // last valid state. I don't know if you have saved it somewhere.
    return; 
  }

  //make ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I played with your codepen and you have some errors in your selectors. As I get confused by your explanation I will try to explain what you could update and how to use it in your code and I hope this is what you need to solve your problem.

First I would change your js to this:

```
var lastSel = $("#buildingSelect").val();
$("#buildingSelect").on("change", function(){
  if ($(this).val()==="2") {
    $(this).val(lastSel);
    return false;
  }
});
```

The proper way to get the value of a select box in jquery is with the `.val()`. In your case you selected the entire selected option element.
I store this value in the `lastSel` variable. Then in the change function the new value of the select list is `$(this).val()`. I check against this value and if it equals 2 I revert it to the value stored in the lastSel variable with this `$(this).val(lastSel)`. 
Keep in mind that the value of a select list is always a string, if you want to check against a number you must first cast it to a numeric value e.g. by using parseInt.

If you want to use the checkDirtyStatus for the check then you should only call this function in the change and pass as parameters the lastSel and the newSel like this:

```
$("#buildingSelect").on("change", function(){
  checkDirtyStatus(lastSel, $(this).val());
});
```

Then you can transfer the logic from the change function into the checkDirtyStatus function and do your checks there. In this case if you wish to revert the select value instead of `$(this).val(lastSel)` you will do a `$("#buildingSelect").val(lastSel)`.

I hope this helps.